# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED Firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I've tried many solutions but none of them seem to work. I'm trying to setup firebase with my android project but I keep getting an error which states `E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED`. Note: Google-services.json is installed into my app directory.

**App:**

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My App:**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest Google play services version? Have you also tried to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`?

Comment: @AlexMamo This whole error went away when I ran it on my physical device...